# How can I remove a bunch of ancient packages on debian?

Tags: debian, package-management, uninstall

I'm running sid, and in the course of trying to [cross-grade](https://wiki.debian.org/CrossGrading) my system from i386 to amd64 I came across some ancient packages that I couldn't remove.  Some background:  I've had this system since potato, or maybe earlier.

There are about a hundred packages like this, so I'd like a generic or scriptable answer.  Here's one example:

```
bminton:/var/cache/apt/archives# dpkg --purge libstdc++2.10-dev
(Reading database ... 1352516 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libstdc++2.10-dev (1:2.95.4-27) ...
install-info: No dir file specified; try --help for more information.
dpkg: error processing package libstdc++2.10-dev (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libstdc++2.10-dev
```

The prerm script `/var/lib/dpkg/info/libstdc++2.10-dev.prerm script contains the following:

```
#! /bin/sh -e



install-info --quiet --remove iostream-2.95
```

Manually running `install-info --quiet --remove iostream-2.95` gives the following error:

```
install-info: No dir file specified; try --help for more information.
```

Comment: How would you know if it is ancient or not?

Comment: *Since potato*?!?  There's gotta be a special club for this, lol.  Are you afraid of just replacing the system?  Methinks keeping it upgraded will eventually unravel into more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: @Networker https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libstdc%2B%2B2.10-dev shows nothing, and http://archive.debian.net/woody/i386/libstdc++2.10-dev shows it.  It also shows up in `aptitude search ?obsolete`

Comment: @Networker Also, libstdc++2.10 is ancient.  Like a decade and a half.  This is looking back into the big bang, debian wise.

Comment: @goldilocks indeed, I have another system that I just installed from scratch, but this is my home desktop and it works.  I know I've had some cruft build up, and I don't think there is anything on here older than woody, but even so, trying to keep it up to date is half the fun.

Comment: @goldilocks I think I have a machine that can join your Potato Club. Upgrades on Debian are supposed to work (and mostly do). Of course, you are supposed to remove the obsolete packages...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by making my own `install-info` command and putting it before `/usr/bin` in `$PATH`.  The script was

```sh
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/install-info "$@" || true
```

Comment: good catch on the "$@"

Comment: FYI: If you want to make sure Gilles actually sees your comment, you need to @-ping him. You can @-ping an editor, even though the name won't tab-complete.

Answer (score 3):

`dpkg` used to have its own `install-info` script which was used in place of the GNU one. An [email about the change](https://lists.debian.org/debian-tex-maint/2009/03/msg00033.html) gives a suggestion for packages (formatting added):

> These packages should just drop their info files in `/usr/share/info`, and call the `update-info-dir` script if present (postinst and prerm). They could suggest/recommend the info package.

So, what I'd suggest you do is edit (yes, edit) `/var/lib/dpkg/info/libstdc++2.10-dev.prerm` and comment out the `install-info ...` line. Do the same for other packages with that failure. Once you're done purging the packages, manually run `update-info-dir`.

BTW: In the future, after doing a upgrade, you should check the list of obsolete/local packages on your system and purge them if not needed. Otherwise, you wind up with very outdated maintainer scripts left lying around.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Linux so that may be terrible advice, but the only thing that worked for me, after trying safer solutions (changing $PATH etc) was to "remove" the old install-info (rename it).

```
> which install-info
/usr/bin/install-info
> mv /usr/bin/install-info install-info.bak
```

I guess this forced him to use the new one.

The upgrade went ultra-smooth after this.